# Getting COM exception when using Interop in a .net app

Tags: c#, com, interop

I've a C# class which uses a COM component using interop.
Here is the sample code:

```
public class MyClass
{

MyCOMClass myObj=null;
try
{
myObj = new MyCOMClass();

for (int num = 0; num < myArr.Length; num++)
{    
  //Call a method on myObj and do some processing
}
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
//log exception
}
finally
{
 if (myObj != null)
            {
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(myObj);
            }

}
}
```

Here, the for loop runs for about 150 times.

n executing this code, in the catch block, am getting an exception :
"COM object that has been separated from its underlying RCW cannot be used."

I tried implementing IDisposable  interface and then writing Dispose method:

```
public class MyClass: IDisposable 
{
 public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true); 
            GC.SuppressFinalize(true); 
        }


        protected virtual void Dispose(bool diposeMgdResources)
        {            
            if (!this.disposed)
            {
                if (diposeMgdResources)
                {
                    if (myObj != null) 
                    { 
                        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(myObj); 
                    } 
                }
                this.disposed = true;
            }
        }
}
```

From the client, I then call dispose on this class like:
myClass.Dispose();

But, still am getting the same exception  here.What am I missing?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Could you paste `//Call a method on myObj and do some processing` code? My first guess is that the object gets cleaned somewhere there.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this article:

[Marshal.ReleaseComObject considered dangerous](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/03/01/marshal-releasecomobject-considered-dangerous.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0)

You probably don't want to call `Marshal.ReleaseComObject()`.